# Spring security requestMatchers with hasAnyAuthority or hasAnyRole not works as expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

In my Spring boot application, I am using the below version in pom.xml. Java version is 17.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
```

My controller class,

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/common")
public class CommonController {

  @GetMapping("/dashboard")
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
  public String userAccess() {
    return "Dash Board Sample.";
  }
}
```

Although I am using @PreAuthorize at the method level, I want to limit access for the url pattern **/api/common/**** to allow only users having the roles "ROLE_USER" or "ROLE_MODERATOR" or "ROLE_ADMIN". But it is not working and giving me 401 when using hasAnyAuthority or hasAnyRole in the filter chain.

Here is my entire SecurityConfig class and I am using the filter chain as follows.

```
import com.example.authservicedemo.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter;
import com.example.authservicedemo.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${spring.security.debug:false}")
    boolean securityDebug;

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/login/**")
                .anonymous()
                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                //.requestMatchers("/api/common/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/common/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_MODERATOR", "ROLE_ADMIN")
                 //.requestMatchers("/api/common/**") .hasAnyRole("USER", "MODERATOR", "ADMIN")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.debug(securityDebug)
                .ignoring()
                .requestMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/lib/**", "/favicon.ico");
    }
}
```

But it gives me 401 error when I access the API.

```
    curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/api/common/dashboard' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY5MTAzNDk4OSwiZXhwIjoxNjkxMTIxMzg5LCJyb2xlcyI6WyJQXzEiLCJQXzMiLCJBXzEiLCJBXzIiLCJBXzMiLCJBXzQiLCJBXzUiLCJST0xFX0FETUlOIl19.8Fp6OPBMsredmLEi2RdB0Bkg0Oa1S_k869mx25CJxEjD01ePys7J7E7mWHRmeeKFMX_ybeDpdK_5loT26eBMAQ'
```

When I uncomment the line **.requestMatchers("/api/common/**").permitAll()** this works well with the method level security @PreAuthorize.
So, how can I limit access to specific URL patterns for users with specific roles?

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Your response would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing anything about dispatcherType filtering? You might need to permitAll on FORWARD if using MVC. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#switch-filter-all-dispatcher-types and read down to the section "Permit FORWARD when using Spring MVC" (if you are using MVC) and add authorize.dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll()

Answer (score 1):

You are using both method-level security annotations (@PreAuthorize) and URL-based security rules. If you are using method-level security (@preAuthorize), the security checks are performed based on the expression specified in the annotation, and URL-based security rules defined in SecurityConfig may not have any effect on those methods.

Also the method level security is recommended to be applied in Service layer. [spring security docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context)

For your security config try using antmatchers as below:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login/**").anonymous()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/common/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_MODERATOR", "ROLE_ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I can use method-level security, but I wonder why URL-based security is not working. I am using requestMatchers as antMatchers is deprecated in the spring-boot version I am using.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer to your question, but check my config. Also you can both have endpoint security and method level security, it is not an issue.

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    
        http
            .userDetailsService(jpaUserDetailsService)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                            .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers( "/auth/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, 
                                "/auth/**").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable) //to be able to use h2- 
                //console and different domains with the login
            .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .logout(logout -> logout
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/login")
            )
            .headers(headers -> headers 
                 .frameOptions(FrameOptionsConfig::disable)) //to be able to use 
                   //h2-console
            .sessionManagement((sessionManagement) -> sessionManagement
                 .sessionConcurrency((sessionConcurrency) ->
                     sessionConcurrency
                         //.maximumSessions(1)
                         //.maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                         .expiredUrl("/auth/login?invalid-session=true")
                         .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
                 )
                 // Set the custom session repository here
                 //.sessionRepository(customSessionRepository()) // Inject your 
                    //custom session repository
            );

            //http.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
            
    return  http.build();
}
```

And here is an example if you want to secure an endpoint based on roles, it is better to use it in the class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/manage-users")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
public class UsersController{
     //some code
}
```

And for method level:

```
@GetMapping("/new")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
public String showRegistrationForm() {
    return "registrationForm";
}
```